Reference outer flat ist item from inner flat list item
I have two flat lists nested inside each other:
<FlatList 
   data={course.sections}
   keyExtractor={(section) => section.id}
   renderItem={({item}) => 
      <View>
        <Text>{item.order}. {item.title}</Text>
        <FlatList 
            data={item.videos}
            keyExtractor={(video) => video.id}
            renderItem={({item}) => 
                <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Video Details' as never)}>
                     <Text>{parentItem.order}.{item.order} {item.title}</Text>
                </Pressable>
            }
         />
     </View>
    }
/>

I need to reference the parent item id from the inner flat list. The code {parentItem.order}. How can I get it to work?
Renaming the item variables to outerItem and innerItem did not work.

You wont be able to reference your outer flatlist item variable as long as it shared the same name as the inner flatlist item variable:
<FlatList
        data={course.sections}
        keyExtractor={(section) => section.id}
        // rename item to section
        renderItem={({ item: section }) => (
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>
              {section.order}. {section.title}
            </Text>
            <FlatList
              data={section.videos}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <Pressable>
                  <Text>
                    {section.order} {item.order}
                  </Text>
                </Pressable>
              )}
            />
          </View>
        )}
      />

